# Data types for parameters of subroutines / functions?

Tags: perl

In Perl, can one specifiy data types for the parameters of subroutines? E.g. when using a dualvar in a numeric context like exit:

```
use constant NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED       => dualvar 3, 'NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED';
exit NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED;
```

How does Perl in that case know, that exit expects a numeric parameter? I didn't see a way to define data types for the parameters of subroutines like you do it in Java? (where I could understand how the data type is known as it is explicitely defined)

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, scalars are both numeric and stringy at the same time. It is not the variables themselves that distinguish between strings and numbers, but the *operators* you work with. While the addition `+` only uses a number, the concatenation `.` only uses strings.

In more strongly typing languages, e.g. Java, the addition operator doubles as addition and concatenation operator, because it can access type information.

`"1" + 2 + 3` is still sick in Java, whereas Perl can cleanly distinguish between `"1" + 2 + 3 == 6` and `"1" . 2 . 3 eq "123"`.

You can force numeric or stringy context of a variable by adding `0` or concatenating the empty string:

```
sub foo {
  my ($var) = @_;
  $var += 0;  # $var is numeric
  $var .= ""; # $var is stringy now
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of the dualvar is that it behaves as a number or text depending on what you want. In cases where that's not obvious (to you more importantly than to perl) then make it clear.

```
exit 0 + NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED;
```

As for explicitly typing parameters, that's not something built in. Perl is a much more dynamic language than Java so it's not common to check/force the type of every parameter or variable. In particular, a perl sub can accept different numbers of parameters and even different structures.

If you want to validate parameters (for an external API for example) try something like [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Params-Validate/)

In addition, [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) and [Moo](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moo) allow a certain level of attribute typing and even coercion.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is quite different from Java in that - `Perl` is `dynamically typed` language, because it does not requires its variables to be typed at `compile time`.. 
Whereas, `Java` is `statically typed` (as you know already)

Perl determines the type of the variable depending upon the `context` it is used..

There can be only `two context`: -

- List Context
- Scalar Context

And the context is defined by the `operator` or `function` that is used..

For EG:-

```
# Define a list
@arr = qw/rohit jain/; 

# Define a scalar
$num = 2

# Here perl will evaluate @arr in scalar context and take its length..
# so, below code will evaluate to : - value = 2 / 2
$value = @arr / $num;

# Here since it is used with a foreach loop, @arr will be taken as in list context
foreach (@arr) {
    say $_;
}
# Above foreach loop will output: - `rohit` \n `jain` to the console..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the type by:

```
use Scalar::Util qw(dualvar);
use constant NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED => dualvar 3, 'NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED';
say NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED;
say int(NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED);
```

**output:**

```
NOTIFY_DIE_MAIL_SEND_FAILED
3
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does Perl in that case know, that exit expects a numeric parameter?

**exit** expect a number as is part of its specification and its behaviour is kind of undefined if you pass it a non-integer value (i.e. you should not do it.

Now, in this particular case, how does **dualvar** manages to return either value type depending of the context?

I don't know how Scalar::Util's **dualvar** is implemented but you can write something similar with [**overload**](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#fallback) instead.

You certainly can modify the behaviour for a blessed object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{package Dualvar;

use overload
    fallback => 1,
    '0+' => sub { $_[0]->{INT_VAL} },
    '""' => sub { $_[0]->{STR_VAL} };

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = { INT_VAL => shift, STR_VAL => shift };
  bless($self,$class);
}

1;
}

my $x = Dualvar->new(31,'Therty-One');

print $x . " + One = ",$x + 1,"\n";    # Therty-One + One = 32
```

From the docs, it seems that **overload** actually changes the behaviour within the declaration scope so you should be able to change the behaviour of some common operators locally for any operand.

If **exit** does use one of those overloadable operations to evaluate its parameter into a integer then this solution would do.

> I didn't see a way to define data types for the parameters of subroutines like you do it in Java?

As already said by others... this is not the case in Perl, at least not at compilation time, except for subroutine [**prototypes**](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/prog/ch06_04.htm) but these don't offer much type granularity (like int vs strings or different object classes).

Richard has mentioned some run-time alternatives you may use. I personally would recommend **Moose** if you don't mind the performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

What Rohit Jain said is correct.  A function that wants input to follow certain rules simply has to explicitly check that the input is valid.

For example

```
sub foo 
{
    my ($param1,$param2) = shift;
    $param1 =~ /^\d+$/ or die "Parameter 1 must be a positive integer.";
    $param2 =~ /^(bar|baz)$/ or die "Parameter 2 must be either 'bar' or 'baz'";

    ...
}
```

This may seem like a pain, but:

- The extra flexibility gained generally outweighs the work involved in doing this.
- Simply having the correct data type is often not enough to ensure that you valid input, so you end up doing a lot this anyway even in a language like Java.